# What is a mode function?

Tags: waves, terminology, fourier-transform, normal-modes

In reading about electrodynamics and quantum mechanics, I have come across the concepts of *mode functions* and *mode solutions*. For example, in Ballentine's *Quantum Mechanics*, the author discusses the mode functions of the EM field [(link)](https://books.google.ca/books?id=sHJRFHz1rYsC&pg=PA527&lpg=PA527&dq=mode%20functions%20wave%20equation&source=bl&ots=RpHSVeka_0&sig=QdgUuZUwPSEv1UKPROZtEFfjwcg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimz-K__7bOAhVD-mMKHceBDR04ChDoAQgaMAA#v=onepage&q=mode%20functions&f=false) when discussing the solution to the wave equation:

> The solution of the wave equation (19.5) can be facilitated by representing the electric field as a sum of *mode functions*, $\textbf{u}_\textit{m}(\textbf{x})...$

Here are my questions and confusions:

1. How are mode functions related to normal modes of vibration?
2. How are mode functions related to the general solution of a differential equation?
3. How would one find the mode functions (in general) for a specific wave
   equation?

Answer (score 2):

I think the explanation is right there in the text, but it might take a bit of translation.  First, notice that the time dependence of a mode field is $e^{-i\omega t}$.  A mode has a single frequency.   Next notice that the "mode function" obeys the eigenvalue equation *and subsidiary conditions* which I take to mean *boundary conditions*.   A mode function is a shape that satisfies both the eigenvalue equation and the boundary conditions.  Multiply a mode function by it's associated time dependence, and you have a solution for the field.

The usefulness of mode functions is that *any* solution, with *any* time dependence and any allowable spatial distribution can be expressed as a sum of the mode fields.